# Is it possible to set custom calendar notification sounds for each calendar event?

Tags: notifications, calendar, htc-sense

I'm trying to create a custom notification sound for a single calendar event. For example, I want to use one mp3 for my reminder to take out the garbage, another for a birthday reminder, etc.

Is this possible? My phone is an HTC One running stock 4.4.2

thanks

Comment: I have not tried the [Caledar Event Reminder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.foobarsoft.calendareventreminder), but it's probably worth checking out. Can't try, because it's paid, and doesn't have a trial version.

Answer (score -3):

1. Download "File Manager (Explorer)" from Google Play List and explore "Notification" Folder.
2. Copy your custom file - MP3 ringtones in the "Notification" folder.
3. Open the Google Calendar --> General Settings --> Sounds --> You can find your custom file to select.

Hope this resolves your clarification.

Comment: They don't want to set a general sound effect. They want a different sound effect for each individual event in the calendar.